# programmatically sending text messages with android dual Sim phones

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm kinda new to android programming and I'm working on an android app that automatically subscribes to a data plan of the user's choice by sending text messages when due. the app runs perfectly fine on my android 4.4.2 but I got stuck somewhere, when I tested the app on a dual Sim phone, I noticed that the text wasn't sent because I believe it couldn't determine which Sim card to send the text through. 
I know this question has been asked before, but trust me I've spent the whole of today going through those questions and answers and no one really answers the question.
I also tried passing the service center number to the sendTextMessage(scAddress) parameter but to no avail
I'd really appreciate it if any could write me a little snippet of code on how to work around it this roadblock. 
thanks in advance cheers.